# randomize query result if no is order given

Tags: django, postgresql, mocking, sql-order-by

I guess there a some places in my django code where we don't do explicit ordering of the DB query.

Of course this is no bug, sometimes the order does not matter.

But since PostgresSQL returns the results most of the time order by primary key I guess we sometime rely on this.

I want to catch these places.

Solution in my mind: Randomize all queries in our tests where not `order by` is given.

I know how to use mock, but have no clue where to mock.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question but any particular reason why you want to randomize when order is not specified?

Comment: That's a great idea, actually. I'd love a way to set a session variable in PostgreSQL to do this, for testing purposes.